# int written to QVariantmap is not a number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qtscript

From a slot function that is accessible from javascript I return a QVariantMap since I want to be the data converted to JavaScript object that contains some primitives.

the code looks like the following:

```
QVariantMap MyObject::createResults()
{
  QVariantMap ret;
  ret["num"] = 23948;
  ret["str1"]   = QString("bla");
  ret["str2"]   = QString("blub");
  return ret;
}
```

the calling script looks like the following:

```
  var myObj = new MyObject();
  var res = myObj.createResults();
  api.cout("typeof(res);      = " +typeof(res));      
  api.cout("typeof(res.num);  = " +typeof(res.num));  
  api.cout("typeof(res.str1); = " +typeof(res.str1)); 
  api.cout("typeof(res.str2); = " +typeof(res.str2));
```

and produces the following output:

```
typeof(res);      = object
typeof(res.num);  = object
typeof(res.str1); = string
typeof(res.str2); = string
```

What do I have to do on the c++ side that `typeof(res.num)` is `number`?

Used Version is Qt 4.8.2

Comment: You are doing something wrong or, possibly, it is a bug in your version of Qt. On my `Qt 5.3.1` build it outputs `number`.

Comment: i tried it also with Qt 4.8.5 with the same result. unfortunately i can not use Qt 5 and i do not know what i am doing wrong but i think it may be a bug. Any idea for a workaround on the c++ side? using `Number(res.num)` in JS fortunately does give the correct number, but it is on the client side.